# kubernetes giving error,but code works

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

every time when deploying this images getting this error`

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
     ^
Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

but code works on pc,I hadn't get error for other deployments they was done this way

dockerfile`

```
FROM node:8.9
ENV port 3000
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD ["sh", "-c", "node index.js --port=${port}"]
```

yaml `

[image]

output of RUN ls -la after COPY ./app

```js
Step 7/8 : RUN ls -la
 ---> Running in 9e24667abd49
total 76
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 Jun 21 07:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 57 root root  4096 Jun 21 07:14 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root    30 May 31 09:00 .dockerignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   151 Jun 21 07:14 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   556 Jun 20 15:16 api.yaml
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 May 23 09:03 controllers
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   446 Jun 20 15:18 index.js
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 May 15 11:27 insert
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 May 15 11:27 modules
drwxr-xr-x 69 root root  4096 Jun 20 15:07 node_modules
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 20404 Jun 20 15:07 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   328 May 31 09:02 package.json
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 May 15 11:27 services
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun 14 14:56 settings
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 May 23 09:35 utilities
```

just forget this!!I've tagged the same container as new version,pushed and its works!

Comment: 1. it is unhelpful to paste a screenshot of a yaml snippet 2. what is the output of `RUN ls -la` right after that `COPY . /app` command?

Comment: running this instead of just node index.js getting the same

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [Grigor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7895517/grigor):

> I've tagged the same container as new version,pushed and its works!